# Trouble getting ruby on rails running on 11.10 (RVM + Passenger + Apache2)

Tags: apache2, rails, rvm

I am running into some issues getting my RoR production server up and running using rvm, passenger, and apache2. I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I am new to ubuntu and it is also my first time setting up a production rails environment using RVM.

Right now with my current setup, when I try to connect to localhost/site-name I get requested url not found from apache.

Here are what my config files look like after having installed rvm, apache2, and passenger.

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/vmcilwain/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger 3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/vmcilwain/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /home/vmcilwain/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/vell:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>`
    ServerName vell 
    DocumentRoot "/home/lmcilwain/vell/current/public"
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/vell-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/vell-access_log" common
<Directory "/var/www/sites/vell/current/public">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
RewriteEngine On
# Remove the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vell$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://vell/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I then create my rail app, run rake db:create to create my database then try to connect via the browser. Which is where I am hitting my snag.

Any help is greatly appreciated and I apologize if this question was answered and I was not able to find it.

Comment: More information is needed, what do you mean by "Which is where I am hitting my snag" ?

Comment: Are you saying that you can't connect to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You should go into the directory for your application and then run the server

ie

```
rails new myApp
cd myApp
rails server
```

after the server starts, go to your browser and type localhost:3000. You should get a Welcome aboard sign.